# iPhone app crashes randomly on device while connecting to remote server?

Tags: iphone, ipad, crash

i have an app which post and get data using webservice it's working fine but while testing the app rigorously crashes with message **Application Exited abnormally with signal 9(Killed)** .

```
Mon Jul 16 21:07:55 unknown MyApp[167] <Warning>: NVVC Dealloc 
        Mon Jul 16 21:08:23 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.company.MyApp[0xe271]) Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:2688 (24132):10 
        Mon Jul 16 21:08:23 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.company.MyApp[0xe271]) Working around 5020256. Assuming the job crashed. 
        Mon Jul 16 21:08:23 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.company.MyApp[0xe271]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation 
        fault 
        Mon Jul 16 21:08:23 unknown SpringBoard[29] <Warning>: Application 'MyApp' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault 
        Mon Jul 16 21:09:04 unknown lockdownd[20] <Error>: (0x403000) handle_connection: Could not receive USB message #7 from Xcode. Killing connection 
        Mon Jul 16 22:00:39 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilemail[0x55fb]) Exited: Killed 
        Mon Jul 16 22:00:39 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilephone[0xa13c]) Exited: Killed 
        Mon Jul 16 22:00:39 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.MyApp.app[0x137]) Exited: Killed 
        Mon Jul 16 22:00:39 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (com.apple.accessoryd) Exited: Killed 
        Mon Jul 16 22:00:41 unknown SpringBoard[29] <Warning>: Application 'Mail' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed 
        Mon Jul 16 22:00:41 unknown SpringBoard[29] <Warning>: Memory level is not normal (15%). Delaying auto-relaunch of 'Mail' for 30 seconds. Mon Jul 16 22:00:41 unknown SpringBoard[29] <Warning>: Application 'app' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed 
        Mon Jul 16 22:00:42 unknown SpringBoard[29] <Warning>: Application 'Phone' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed
```

i googled around but i could not found any solution or reason for killing app.please Help me to resolve the issue.

Edit#2
Here i am adding some code where i am getting crash in my application.

```
 @try {

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    NSUserDefaults *defaults2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:URL];

                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: url];
                // NSURLRequest *request =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:synStr]];
            NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
            [connection start];
            [connection release];
            if(label != nil){
       progressView = [[ProgressView showHUDAddedTo:self.tabBarController.view animated:YES]retain];
       progressView.labelText = label;
        }

       [request release];
           }
    @catch (NSException * e) {   
    }
```

Comment: its hard to say without looking at your code.

Comment: Why do you post this question twice and there are many other who posted the same crash log. Start with those old question answers and tips to see if you can better identify the problem.

Comment: Dear janusfidel, see my second edit for code here the piece of code i am suspecting for crash.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `NSURLConnection` incorrectly. If you look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you can see that you are starting an asynchronous connection. It looks like you are releasing the connection object before it has finished, which is causing the segmentation fault.